# Receive object datatype from back4app in react

Tags: reactjs, object, get, datagrid, back4app

I have an issue with receiving the datatype object from the database in back4app in the column "expiration" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5C7ur.png). I have no issue with receiving the other datatypes (String, Array..), but I can't deconstruct the object into day, month and year.

I have the following code where I receive the other datatypes and save it in an useState:

```
const [ideaTable, setIdeaTable] = useState();

  async function fetchIdeas() {
    const query = new Parse.Query("Idea");
    try {
      const ideas = await query.find();
      console.log("Parse Objects: ", ideas);
      const destructuredIdeas = destructureIdeas(ideas);
      setIdeaTable(destructuredIdeas);
      console.log("from readIdeas: ", ideaTable);
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      alert(`Error ${error.message}`);
      return false;
    }
  }

  function destructure(idea) {
    return {
      id: idea.id,
      title: idea.get("title"),
      section: idea.get("tags"),
      author: idea.get("author"),
/*        expiration: JSON.stringify(idea.get("expiration")) */
      expiration: idea.get("expiration")
       
    };
  }

  function destructureIdeas(ideas) {
    return ideas.map(destructure);
  }
```

[Here I just call: "expiration: idea.get("expiration")" as in above code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbTjs.png) So, I think I need to restructure the expiration object to get the day, month and year... but how?

If I do this: "expiration: JSON.stringify(idea.get("expiration"))", I get the following result [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVkXS.png).

**So, what to do if I want to display for example: "14.12.2021"?**

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself:

```
expiration: idea.get("expiration").day
expiration: idea.get("expiration").month
expiration: idea.get("expiration").month
```